# ¿Como agregar una variable a un path?

Tags: python

Hola deseo agregar una variable a la opción open para poder abrir un archivo con el clasico:

```
open = ("path/archivo.txt","a")
```

Lo que quiero es reemplazar archivo por una variable que ya tengo definida.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**OBJETOS PATH**

Para eso utilizamos la librería `pathlib` que viene integrada con funciones que evitaran errores inesperados. La librería convierte las rutas en objetos `Path`.

```
from pathlib import Path

ruta = Path("path")
variable = "archivo.txt"
ruta_con_variable = ruta.joinpath(mi_variable)
```

Eso creará un objeto `Path` de tu ruta `path/archivo.txt`, al cual le puedes pedir diferentes parametros de esa ruta.

```
ruta_con_variable.parent  # Nombre de la carpeta donde se encuentra
ruta_con_variable.name  # Nombre del archivo
ruta_con_variable.stem  # Nombre de archivo sin extensión
ruta_con_variable.suffix  # Extensión
ruta_con_variable.exists()  # Comprueba si el archivo existe
```

Lista completa en https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

**PATH A STRING**

En caso de necesitar la ruta completa en string, basta con utilizar `resolve()`:

```
ruta_en_string = ruta.joinpath(mi_variable).resolve()
```

La ventaja de `resolve()` es que analiza tu sistema y crea una ruta válida independientemente de si estás en linux, en windows, si necesitas / o \\ o \ o lo que sea.

**EJEMPLO COMPLETO**

Una vez creado, ya puedes utilizarlo en operaciones como esta:

```
from pathlib import Path

ruta = Path("path")
ruta_con_variable = ruta.joinpath("archivo.txt").resolve()
with open(ruta_con_variable, "a") as file:
    # tu código
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya intento concatenar la variable al path dentro de los parametros de la funcion `open`
Es decir:

```
o = open("path/"+variable, "a")
```

Comment: Uf eso es muy mala idea, puede dar cantidad de erroes, deberias usar objetos `Path`.

Comment: Ah, no tenia conocimiento que algo asi podia pasar, pues nunca me habia pasado pero siendo asi tomare la respuesta tuya para aplicarla siempre.