# Agregar fecha actual en el nombre de un archivo en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy utilizando la libreria de Shutil con Python para mover un archivo de una carpeta a otra carpeta, hasta eso todo sale bien pero quisiera que al momento de mover el archivo se le agregue la fecha actual y no se como podria hacer eso hasta ahora estoy moviendo 3 archivos y este es mi codigo

```
import shutil
import datetime

    shutil.move("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads/planrecursos_uemp.xls","/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+/planrecursos_uemp.xls")
    shutil.move("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads/planrecursos_uemp (1).xls","/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+/planrecursos_uemp (1).xls")
    shutil.move("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads/planrecursos_uemp (2).xls","/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+/planrecursos_uemp (2).xls")
```

De antemano, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pondré primero con muchos pasos extra para que lo entiendas bien, utilizando objetos `Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path  
import shutil
import datetime

# 1: Creas un Path de la ruta antigua
desde = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads/planrecursos_uemp.xls")
# 2: Consigues el nombre del archivo, la fecha, y los juntas
archivo = desde.name
fecha = str(datetime.datetime.now())
archivo_con_fecha = f"{fecha}_{archivo}"
# 3: Creas un Path de la ruta nueva
hasta = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+").joinpath(archivo_con_fecha)
# 4: Y a moverlos
shutil.move(desde.resolve(), hasta.resolve())
```

**Para más información sobre como funciona `Path`, lee este mensaje:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/322506/24973**

Y para simplificar el código:

```
from pathlib import Path  
import shutil
import datetime

desde = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads/planrecursos_uemp.xls")
archivo = f"{str(datetime.datetime.now())}_{desde.name}"
hasta = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+").joinpath(archivo)
shutil.move(desde.resolve(), hasta.resolve())
```

**Bonus:** Para los 3 archivos (o más) lo que yo haría sería un bucle:

```
from pathlib import Path  
import shutil
import datetime

archivos = ["planrecursos_uemp.xls", "planrecursos_uemp (1).xls", "planrecursos_uemp (2).xls"]

desde = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Downloads")
hasta = Path("/Users/ecastrop/Desktop/Reporte people+")
for nombre in archivos:
    nombre_nuevo = f"{str(datetime.datetime.now())}_{nombre}"
    shutil.move(desde.joinpath(nombre).resolve(), hasta.joinpath(nombre_nuevo).resolve())
```

Así no tienes que tocar absolutamente nada del código para mover 500 archivos, tan solo tienes que añadir el nombre de los archivos que quieras mover a la lista `archivos`.

Comment: muchas gracias, me resulto perfecto solo agregue una cosa mas por un detalle que me salia en la fecha pero todo resulto perfecto

Comment: Sí, siempre adapta el código a tus necesidades. Así es como se aprende.